# i3blocks.conf Error could not parse JSON lexical error

Tags: shell-script, scripting, i3, rss-aggregator

I have this error in my `/etc/i3blocks.conf`

`Error: Could not parse JSON (lexical error: invalid bytes in UTF8 string.)`

My code in `/etc/i3blocks.conf` looks like this.

```
[rss]
command=rsstail -n1 -1 -N -u https://stackexchange.com/feeds/questions | head -c 50
color=#00FF00
interval=300

[rss]
command=rsstail -n1 -1 -N -u https://unix.stackexchange.com/feeds | head -c 50
color=#00FF00
interval=60

[rss]
command=rsstail -n1 -1 -N -u https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/feeds | head -c 50
color=#00FF00
interval=300

[rss]
command=rsstail -n1 -1 -N -u https://news.ycombinator.com/rss | head -c 50
color=#00FF00
interval=300
```

It's because RSS title contains not allowed characters. Otherwise I have not this error.
How can I fix or handle this error in my `/etc/i3blocks.conf`? So that, if one RSS channel doesn't work, the other three will work?

Comment: Try setting the locale to a utf8 variant, eg `command=LC_ALL=en_GB.utf8 rsstail ...`.

Comment: @meuh After `i3-msg restart` I have the same error. Shouldn't second `=` be excaped somehow?

Comment: I don't see any examples where the `=` is escaped.  You might try piping the rsstail output through `iconv -f UTF-8 -t ASCII//TRANSLIT`, which should replace the bad code with something in ascii. If you prefer use `iso-8859-15` instead of ascii. Do this before the `head`. Note: `head` might cause a problem as it could cut off a utf8 sequence of bytes at midpoint, creating a bad codepoint, hence the value in converting to an encoding that only uses 1 byte per char.

Comment: @meuh This helped. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `head -c 50` might cause a problem as it could cut off a utf8 sequence
of bytes at midpoint, creating a bad codepoint. If you need to use it you
can instead convert the multichar output to an encoding that only uses 1
byte per char, such as ascii or iso-8859-15.

It might be enough to just set this in the locale environment to `rsstail`:

```
command=LC_ALL=iso-8859-15 rsstail ...
```

Alternatively, if there really is bad code coming from rsstail, and assuming the output from rsstail is probably in utf8, you can pipe the output through `iconv`,  asking it to transliterate the bad code with something else:

```
command=rsstail ... | iconv -f UTF-8 -t iso-8859-15//TRANSLIT | head ...
```